# What does "sampled surfaces incontinently" mean, exactly?

Tags: phrases

In their Story of Civilization, Will and Ariel Durant have this to say about Wellington's early years:

> Like Byron, he proposed to a noble lady, was rejected and **sampled
> surfaces incontinently**. In 1796 he went to India as a colonel under
> his brother Richard ...

What do they mean, exactly?

Comment: Perhaps it's a whimsical way of saying *he went on extended trips abroad* (to land surfaces ***on other continents***) to get over his failed romance.

Comment: ...actually, no. It's listed as "archaic" in the full OED, but the sense here is archaic - ***straightway, at once, immediately***. But in context, the cited usage still looks to me like wordplay / punning.

Comment: I think it means that Wellington had a number of superficial ("surface") relationships.

Comment: My take: (After being rebuffed) He sampled = frequented/traveled to; surfaces = places/countries + OED:  "incontinently--In an incontinent manner; loosely, **unchastely**." Next sentence has him in India.

Comment: Like Byron, he was rejected by a woman and had a series of casual affairs with men: the likely reading.

Comment: @Xanne - I've never heard any suggestion that Wellington was bisexual.

Comment: @KateBunting Interesting. But the Durants go on to say that he later married the same woman, and they were unhappy but learned to live apart.

Comment: @KateBunting From Wikipedia: Wellesley was married by his brother Gerald, a clergyman, to Kitty Pakenham in St Georges Church, Dublin on 10 April 1806.[197] They had two children: Arthur was born in 1807 and Charles was born in 1808. The marriage proved unsatisfactory and the two spent years apart, while Wellesley was campaigning and afterward. Kitty grew depressed, and Wellesley pursued other sexual and romantic partners.[99][198] Not sure how good these sources are, but the article looks well-referenced.

Comment: Why say “like Byron” if he merely got turned down? Being turned down is hardly unusual.

Comment: @Xanne - Oh, yes, I know about the Duke's unfortunate marriage and that he had many affairs, but I never heard it suggested that he had them with other men.